# CUBA Platform and use and throw UI prototyping

Tags: cuba-platform

I like to use the CUBA-Platform as a high fidelity wireframe building, that is Create UI using drag and drop, Deploy without dependency on the CUBA backend, ONly the User-interface is important.  Any option to deploy CUBA UI without CUBA Backend?

Edit: Closing this ticket as the CUBA Platform changed a lot after asking this question. CUBA's purpose is not the wireframe generation but they treated it as a nice suggestion.

Comment: i think this is unfortunately not possible, although it is an interesting idea. But oftentimes you you also want to add test data etc, so you probably need a backend anyway, right? What concerns do you have regarding deploying backend as well? You can use also use a single war.

Comment: Thanks @MarioDavid We are taking approvals in the Ui before implementing it. Data is not important only UI, So the customer is not ready to allow to setup the backend ( java server, Database etc..) . one example for this one is https://proto.io/, If CUBA will support this we can re use the code for final implementataion too...